# Swift: Why is Apple's Numbers .TSV export unable to have its values parsed by the tab character?

Tags: swift, csv, tabs, numbers

I'm working on a basic localization pipeline where a spreadsheet exports values as TSV (tab-separated values).

Numbers exports "TSV" but the output does not show a `\t` character.  If I open this .tsv in a text editor, the tab character is there.  It also doesn't let me specify my delimiter.

Now, in swift, if I read this file, line by line, I would expect to get all my column values with this:

`let columns = line.components(separatedBy: "\t")`

But it does not return multiple values.

Does anyone know how to separate by tabs ?

Comment: `.components(separatedBy: "\t")` works fine for me. Please add an reproducible example.

Comment: It's hard to add a reproducible example due to the way text is rendered, copied and pasted.

Comment: So you're saying you used numbers to export to TSV, you read this content in with `String(contentsOf: urlToThatFile)` and then line by line, you executed `.components(separatedBy: "\t")` and it worked fine for you?

I'm on the latest MacOS 13.4.1 and Xcode 14.3.1

Comment: I am running Xcode 15 beta and reproduced in a playground if that could have made a difference but yes my code is the same otherwise.

Comment: Well I'm not up here lying to anyone, I'm helping communicate what gave me problems so to save others time.

Comment: if your tabs were made with \t they will be separated with \t.  if they were produced with "Indent with Tabs", they will not.  If you try to use the tab character in your string literal, Xcode will also complain.  So you'd have to use "\u{0009}"

Answer (score 0):

It often happens this way.  The answer presents itself shortly after the question.

The key is to use the unicode value and not `\t`, as Numbers exports the tabs as unicode values, not as '\t'.

i.e. `line.components(separatedBy: "\u{0009}")`

And you should note that if you're editing files in Xcode to create a test case, you should set "indent with" to Tabs and not Spaces.

Comment: The following all yields the same result for me: `.components(separatedBy: "\t")`, `.components(separatedBy: "\u{0009}")` and `.components(separatedBy: .controlCharacters)`

Comment: `\t` and `\u{0009}` is the same character. `print("\t" == "\u{0009}")` prints `true`.

Comment: I don't know what I should tell you; one way worked, one way didn't.  There are many ways in which text is encoded, interpreted, exported, and so on.